# Java 2d Array Matrix Program(Sum of Prime Numbers)

Tags: java, arrays

```
for(i=2;i<=5;i++) {
        for(j=2;j<=(i/2);j++) {
            if(i%j== 0) {
                j=i;
                break;
            }
        }
        if(i!=j) {
            sum +=i;            
        }
    }
    System.out.println("The sum of all prime numbers is : "+sum);
```

> What I'm trying to achieve is the sum of all prime numbers when I run my program, i am using this code but then the sum is not what I think it is. The sum is greater than what I expected it. I tried rewriting and changing some but the result is as is. Other informations: The matrix is randomized from 0-9, it is a (5x5)2D array.

Comment: You need a condition to check if a number is prime or not. Which part of your code you think is checking that?

Comment: You do not check the contents of the 2D array in your code if it's prime or not.  There should be a method like `boolean isPrime(int x)`

Answer (score 0):

You should take into account the specific requirement that array elements are randomized from 0 to 9, thus you have to check for the following primes below 10: [2, 3, 5, 7].

Then iterate the matrix and sum up all primes:

```java
private static boolean isPrimeBelow10(int x) {
    return x == 2 || x == 3 || x == 5 || x == 7;
}

public static int sumPrimes(int[][] arr) {
    int sum = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < arr[i].length; j++) {
            if (isPrimeBelow10(arr[i][j])) {
                sum += arr[i][j];
            }
        }
    }
}
```

If you needed to handle larger elements, then you would have to maintain an extendable list of primes and add new elements to it as necessary.

Comment: The `x < 10` condition is redundant.

Comment: Yeah I added it just in case a value above the specified range is provided - because the method is not checking for any primes.  Though it would be better to throw an `IllegalArgumentException` then.

Comment: "in case a value above the specified range is provided"—But it doesn't have any effect even if that does happen.

Comment: Output the array elements.
Output the sum of each row.
 Output the sum of each column.
 Output the sum of all the elements.
 Output the sum of prime numbers in the array.
 Output the sum of the elements in the main diagonal.
 Output the sum of the elements below the diagonal.
Output the sum of the elements above the diagonal.
Output the sum of odd numbers below the diagonal.
Output the sum of even numbers above the diagonal.

Comment: It contains all my other codes and it affects the codes below it.